# Define items with a custom name in preamble, use them in the document

Tags: preamble

I have items such as `\myphone` and several others defined in a `preamble.sty` file and would like to reference these items in my document using this name (similar to CSS classes). How does this mechanism work?

In the preamble:

`\def\myphone{555-5555}`

In the document:

`\lhead{myphone}`

Comment: `\lhead{\myphone}` perhaps? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The exact terminology here would not be 'items'. In LaTeX usually one would say 'macros'.

What you are looking for is what the KOMA classes do internally:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\SetChrisVar[2]{%
  \@namedef{chrisvar@#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand*\UseChrisVar[2]{%
  \@nameuse{chrisvar@#1}%
}
\makeatother

\SetChrisVar{myphone}{555-5555}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \lhead{\UseChrisVar{myphone}}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\null
\end{document}
```

`\SetChrisVar` assigns a value (`#2`) to a internal macro `\chrisvar@<#1>` and `\UseChrisVar` fetches its value. Nice and simple ;)

(And as a brief sidenote please keep in mind that `\lhead` is a macro from `fancyhdr` that sets the left header and is not meant to be used in the document.)